# Drupal for Firebug does not work in FF> Works fine in Chrome

Tags: debugging

I have downloaded and installed Drupal for firebug Module and FF and Chrome extensions.

I log in as admin (uid 1) and do a simple output call:

```
firep("this is some message", "Message Title");
```

On chrome I can see the output fine, but in firefox I get the following message:

> No Drupal for Firebug data was found.

Either this site is not running Drupal or the Drupal for Firebug module has not been installed/enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the Drupal for Firebug plugin depending on which version of Firefox/Firebug/DrupalForFirebug you are running.  See the following issue on DO [Extension breaks with version 14 of Firefox](http://drupal.org/node/1691908)

It works for me on:

```
Firefox - 18.0.2
Firebug - 1.11.2
Drupal for Firebug Module - 7.x-1.4
Drupal for Firebug Firefox Plugin - 2.2
```

Comment: Reverted my Firefox from 19 back to 18 and it works ok now. Thanks

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  The extension seemed to break at FF14 then got fixed at FF17. Pity it's broken again.